# Combine an observable with the results of its pipe into a single observable

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm querying a nested RESTful API using Angular's `HttpClient` module. Retrieving a complete entity requires fetching data from several endpoints the links to which are stored in the response of the first request.

I'm using `forkJoin` to send the 2, 3, 4th, etc. requests in parallel. This works great, however, I "lose" the result of the first request. My current solution is to include it in the `forkJoin` by turning the result of the request to an observable through the `of()` operator

```js
this.http.post(url, geoRequest, httpOptions).pipe(
  concatMap(resp => {
    return forkJoin(
      of(resp),
      this.http.get(resp[0]["_links"].endpointA.href, httpOptions),
      this.http.get(resp[0]["_links"].endpointB.href, httpOptions)
    );
  })
);
```

This results in an array with three elements each containing the result of each request. Perfect. However, "recreating" the initial observable (through `of(resp)`) feels a bit hacky and I'm wondering if there is a more elegant solution to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you're doing is perfectly fine but I understand that it looks kind of weird.

So you could for example use `map` to append/prepend the first result:

```
return forkJoin(
    this.http.get(...),
    this.http.get(...),
  )
  .pipe(
    map(results => [resp, ...results]),
  )
```

The `forkJoin` operator has also so called "result selector" function which means you could use the `map` callback as the last parameter after listing all source Observables. However this was removed it RxJS 6 so you shouldn't use it any more.

https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/MIGRATION.md#howto-result-selector-migration

Comment: Thanks, that's a nice way of doing it.